# Adapting an older schematic for use with recent components: How might this circuit need to change?

Tags: circuit-design, serial, bluetooth, infrared

The schematic below is a bidirectional bluetooth-to-infrared serial device.

- Computer sends bits to device via bluetooth virtual COM port.
- Device re-transmits bits via 950nm IR w/ 38khz carrier frequency.
- Device can also receive IR signal, transmitting back to the computer via BT.
  [image]

U1 is [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/NE555P/296-1411-5-ND/277057), which creates the 38kHz freqency.
U2 is [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10266), which receives an IR signal.
U3 is [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/LM2931AZ-5.0RAG/LM2931AZ-5.0RAGOSCT-ND/917934), which regulates a 5V supply for the IR receiver.
My problem is that the [SparkFun BluesmiRF module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12577) is no longer a 9V device: **it now operates on 3.3V to 6V**, and the TX pin outputs at the same voltage as PWR. So my questions are:

1. Should I connect **C** to **D** to power the BT module with the regulator U3, or just use a voltage divider? I believe U3 can handle the extra current.
2. In the original circuit, TX was likely 9V; it is now 5V. Does R7 or transistor **A** need to change to compensate?
3. U1's RST pin calls for 0.3V to 1V. If TX is at 5V instead of 9V, will voltage divider **B** still output 0.3V to 1V?
4. I'm fairly new to electronics. Anything else I should consider before attempting this build?

Comment: Try powering the whole thing from 5V. It will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at one of the datasheets for the55 timer. It will operate on 4.5V. That is good.

R8 and R9 will probably need to change so the reset pin keeps the same voltage range. The existing combination seems strange to me as the max would be `(9V - 0.2V) * (3.3k / (3.3k + 47k))` or about `0.577 volts`. `R8` should probably be `0 ohms`

Where do you find the specification for 0.3 to 1V on the reset pin?

The voltage change shouldn't affect the 38 khz frequency that the 555 timer generates.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've been looking at [this documentation](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf) for the timer. Unless I'm reading it wrong, page 5 lists 0.3-1V for the RST pin. It appears that the transistor is functioning as a switch in this setup - would the 5V base voltage from TX still toggle the transistor?

Comment: For the reset pin: a voltage on this pin below a certain level activates the reset. This level is typically 0.7 volts. It could be as low as 0.3 volts or as high as 1 volt. It should be driven to ground or to the same voltage as the supply pin